# Instantiating a Class as a Class Attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand why I cannot instantiate a defined class as another's class attribute. What is happening exactly and what is the Python logic behind it? Is there any workaround that would allow me to use an instance of the class as a class attribute (static attribute)?

```
class FirstClass():
    class_var = SecondClass()
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = "Instance VAR"


class SecondClass():
    def print_msg(self):
        print "SecondClassMessage"


first_class = FirstClass()
print first_class.class_var
```

It gives me this: `NameError: name 'SecondClass' is not defined`

Comment: You *can* do that, but **only if** `SecondClass` has *already been defined* when you try to instantiate it. Switch the definition order of the classes...

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you wouldn't mind to convert that to an answer and expand a little I will accept. It worked.

Comment: What's to expand? Python can't create an object before you've told it how to do so!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement

```
class_var = SecondClass()
```

is contained in the body of `FirstClass` and is therefore directly executed when the *class* is created. At this time the name `SecondClass` has not yet been introduced, which is why the interpreter complains.

This is in contrast to statements that are contained in the `__init__` method of a class, they are not executed until an *instance* is created.

So, as others have already said, you must define `SecondClass` before `FirstClass`.

Comment: Not the first, but most precise and explanatory answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The proper fix is to rearrange the classes so that they exist by the time you try to use them.

If this is for some reason not possible then you can add the attribute to the class afterward, provided it isn't needed for some other use while creating the classes... and if it *is* needed then you have a seriously broken-ass architecture that needs some very real rethinking.

Answer (score 1):

```
class SecondClass():
    def print_msg(self):
        print "SecondClassMessage"

class FirstClass():
    class_var = SecondClass()
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = "Instance VAR"

first_class = FirstClass()
print first_class.class_var
```

EDIT: 
You have to change the order so that Python knows what SecondClass is. Otherwise you have to assign SecondClass to FirstClass later when all the classes are loaded into memory.

If you explain why you need this we could possibly give you a better way of doing it.

Comment: It might be helpful to write a short paragraph explaining what you've changed, and why.

Answer (score 1):

While others are correct that re-arranging the order you define the classes will allow it to work, I prefer to initialize to `None` then instantiate in the `__init__` :

```
class FirstClass():
    class_var = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = "Instance VAR"
        if FirstClass.class_var is None:
            FirstClass.class_var = SecondClass()

class SecondClass():
    def print_msg(self):
        print "SecondClassMessage"

first_class = FirstClass()
print first_class.class_var
```

It does put an additional `if` block in the code.  But, re-arranging things does not break anything.  I also think it makes the intent clearer.

Comment: I prefer this answer over the accepted as it solves the chicken-egg problem when, at some point, you also want to add the FirstClass to the second.